# How to fix " Could not compile `user32-sys" error in Rust

Tags: rust

;)
My file `cargo.tml` contains

```
...
[dependencies]
winapi = "0.2.7"
user32-sys = "0.2"
```

And my main.rs

```
extern crate winapi;
extern crate user32;
```

But, when i use `cargo build`. I have this error:

```
error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `user32-sys`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Comment: The first line of the error message is "aborting due to previous error". What is that previous error?

Comment: The previous error: https://snag.gy/CyG5ke.jpg

Comment: Cargo tries to call the Microsoft linker, but instead finds the completely unrelated GNU `link` utility, which creates a hard link to a file. Fix your search path so Cargo can find `link.exe`.